# Android sqlite database version change

Tags: android, sql, sqlite

I have an app with a database and in my new app version the database schema has to be changed.

Where should the old and the new version be added in the code? How will the new version compare the database with the old version and make changes.

Please help me with this.

Comment: Please post some code.

Answer (score 0):

```
Override onUpgrade method in SQLiteOpemHelper class.

@Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("TAG", "ugrade called");
        if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + SchoolCode.CODE_LIST_TABLE);
            // db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ParentTable.PARENT_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "
                    + PreferenceTable.PREFERENCE_LIST_TABLE);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + ParentTable.PARENT_TABLE);
            onCreate(db);
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//first DATABASE_VERSION add 1,bigger than your old version 
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;
public ExpenseDBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase paramSQLiteDatabase, int oldVersion,
        int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        // old version database ,you can upgrade data here
     }

    if (newVersion == 2) {
        // new version database ,you can add data or table here
     }


}
```